# how to make only toggle visible at a time in the screen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap toggle, which will expand and collapse. But I have two of them in the screen. I don't want both of them to be seen at a time. That is at one point of time, only one toggle can be shown, and if the user clicks the other toggle, the previous toggle should collapse. I don't know how the internal is working, because all I am using is a class name. How to have to control for this over jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2  options " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
</div>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
</div>


<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2  options " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
</div>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion
```